# Porting iOS app to Android

Tags: android, ios, porting

we made a quit big iOS application with 2000+ objective c classes. I am wondering there is a best practice guide to port it to Android ? Currently I am looking at Visual Paradigm (UML) which reverse engineers objective c files to UML. Like Enterprise Architect it also allows me to generate code(headers + declaration) for another popular language like java or c++. Are there any other approaches yet ? Also, as our app is heavily using the UINavigation and UIView controllers, I am wondering there is similar model and implementation on Android.

Thanks so far, guenter

Comment: How in the world did you end up with 2000+ classes?  Even my most complex application, where I have stub classes for many of my managed object entities, only ends up with ~100 classes.

Comment: Check https://www.myappconverter.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all honesty, I think that what you are planing is just going to make for crappy code that will be insanely hard to maintain. I realize it sounds like a lot of work, but its gonna be easier in the long run, I would just "port" the concept of the app to android and write it from the ground up.

Comment: I just had a look on the generated code, in the cases of struct like objects being used for storage only it seems a good deal. You're definitely right for objects performing logical issues such as view controllers.

Comment: You are right, for data structures it seems like it could work, but because of the way android works I dont really see any way to do the conversion easily. Your NIB file will now have to be written in android friendly XML, and you wont have any delegates to "connect" and instead you will manage the object by calling the directly from the activity that uses the XML layout. Its very different.

Comment: I recently did the inverse process, I developed my App in Android first, and when I went to do it in iOS it just seemed like a better idea to copy the concept and design it just for iOS. A big issue is that phone users want apps to feel like the phone they are using, so while your app may do the same thing it will probably do it diferently. I hope you understand what I mean with that, theres a reason why people buy android or iOS and they dont want to feel apps like a direct port.

Answer (score 4):

**The Apportable SDK**

It cross-compiles Objective-C applications to Android, without extensive changes to the original codebase. Instead of translating the code to Java, Apportable cross-compiles your code to run directly on the Android device’s processor, bypassing the Java runtime, resulting in speed and performance that rivals the iOS version.

The platform has been tested on Apportable’s library of over 150 devices and in the wild, where Apportable-powered apps have received 5-star reviews on thousands of devices.

check out the sdk [here](http://www.apportable.com/?utm_source=iosdevtips&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=main)

Answer (score 1):

For going from C or C++ to Android you are probably best of using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). The problem is that I don't think this is possible (at least, not directly?) for Objective C.

I think it might be best to try and go to C, and then use the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) to make it into an app for Android. Going from your code, trough UML to JAVA sounds like a much harder option.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am gathering information which other platforms are left  supporting c++.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no automatic tool to convert Objective-C to Java. There is [java2objc](http://code.google.com/p/java2objc/wiki/UsageGuide) that does the reverse.

Here are some official tips for porting Objective-C to Java: http://www.nextcomputers.org/NeXTfiles/Software/WebObjects/Guides/PortingObjectiveCtoJava.pdf

I'm not an iOS expert, but AFAIK iOS does not have layout managers - it uses XIB/NIB to do layout (or dynamically in code, which is not recommended). On Android there are layout classes which are primarily used to support different resolutions. Also, layout is [declared via XML files.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

So it seems there is a lot of hand-coding in front of you. Since a project is quite large, I'd get a help of an expert that knows both Android and iPhone.

Comment: thanks for the links, we have excellent Java expertise just not for Android.

Answer (score 0):

just to let you know how the story did end up, I kept using Sparx Enterprise Architect and have my design, architecture and documentation well under control, for all platforms finally except for JavaScript. Its a bit tedious when integrating new features but in an enterprise environment it saved me a lot of time. We are working on iOS, Desktop(Web2.0/HTML5), Android, Blackberry, Symbian and some router systems. To get rid of platform specific things, I introduced always an additional layer. Seems to work for our products so far.

Thanks to all again, g.

Comment: obj-c classes can use c/c++ natively so c/c++ is the best option for a cross-platform approach, with e.g. C to JS/Flash compiler for HTML5... btw didn't know symbian and blackberry were still alive ;)

Answer (score 0):

**MyAppConverter**  service helps to convert native iOS mobile apps instantly to native Android app, it's not focused mainly on the look and feel, and UI interaction of your app. That means it don't replicate your application as it is. Instead, MyAppConverter make all changes to make a project suitable for the development of an Android application.

MyAppConverter currently support only ***iOS*** to ***Android*** conversion and ***objective-c*** to ***swift***.